# ES6 destructure and spread together as arguments into a React Component

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I understand ES6 destructure and spread operators, but I am confused by their usage together. Can someone break this down into a way a layman can understand?

```
const index = ({title, description, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

How does this work?

Comment: That's not spread, it's *rest syntax* - part of the destructuring syntax. It collects "everything else" into `props` - in this case, anything that is not `title` or `description`

Comment: See [rest in object destructuring on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring)

Comment: From the MDN link above: `let {a, b, ...rest} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40}; //rest = { c: 30, d: 40 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Where `everythingElseExceptTitleAndDescription` creates a new object with all enumerable own properties of the argument except `title` and `description`

```
const index = (arg) => {
  let title = arg.title;
  let description = arg.description;
  let props = everythingElseExceptTitleAndDescription(arg);
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```